# に in passive sentence

Tags: particle-に

乱暴にされているのに....

Got the sentence above from a book. From what I understand, に marks the doer in a passive sentence. In other words, the sentence above would translate to "done by violence", which doesn't makes sense to me. What is this に trying to mark here?

Comment: Hint: 乱暴 is also a na-adjective.

Comment: @user3856370 Cheers

Comment: which  に are you asking about?

Comment: TBH, "done by violence" makes perfect sense to me, it simply means "sb did sth with/using violence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

に, like most Japanese particles, can have a number of possible uses.

In a passive sentence, に *can* mark the actor (similar to "by" in English), but in a passive sentence, に can also be used in any of the same ways it can be used in other sentences, too, so just because it *can* be used that way doesn't mean it necessarily *is*.

In this case, as you noted, interpreting it as indicating the person/thing doing the action does not make a lot of sense, so that's probably not the right meaning.  What is the right meaning?  Well, 乱暴 can be an adjective ("violent"), に is commonly used to form adverbs from adjectives (*adjective* + に --> *adverb*), so without other context this seems like the straightforward interpretation:

> 乱暴 ("violent") + に (adverb) --> 乱暴に ("violently")
>   乱暴に ("violently") + されている ("is being done") --> 乱暴にされている ("is being done violently")